# Cordova plocal-notification plugin issue

Tags: cordova

I want my cordova sndroid application to show local notifications.
when application starts it will make messeges and will show in notification area.
for that i am using local notification plugin.below it is:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/
i have implemented it step by step.always geeting error likke : "cannot read property local of Undefined".
do i misiing something?
need help.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add files inside `www` folder.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/master/www